# Trying to understand use cases of web sockets in a node app

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, pusher-js

I was told a good use of websockets would be if you had an app that showed stock prices, which fluctuate constantly.  You’d want all the clients to update these new prices at the same time so on the server, you can emit an event that updates these stocks and have all the clients listen for these events so that they get the new data to display.

On the server though, wouldn’t you constantly need to be polling the api you’re getting these stock prices to see if there’s a change and *then* emit these out to the clients?  I don’t know how you’d get away without constantly polling an outside api to get the data you need before you send an emitted event to your clients.

Comment: The same way: Subscribe to a channel that pushes notifications to you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but if you’re getting your data from an outside api you don’t have control from, how would you do that without constantly polling

Comment: As T.J. Crowder said; this outside API will ideally also expose a websocket interface for you to use... (of course if it doesn't, you have to poll, yes. but normally API providers which give you realtime data don't want that either, because it's much computationally more expensive and consumes more bandwidth, so they will usually have some sort of websocket API for that very reason, often even just sending _deltas_ (difference to the last dataset) instead of pushing all the data every time)

Comment: For example: https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md

Comment: Got it, makes sense now!  Thank you both!!